# Problema : Establecer SelectedValue en DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, combobox, datagrid

Un **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** no tiene las propiedades `SelectedIndex`, y `SelectedValue`. Sin embargo, quiero obtener el mismo comportamiento del `SelectedValue`

> Tengo un `DataGridView` que contiene varias columnas de las cuales tengo una tipo `ComboBoxColumn`, sucede que para llenar ese `DatagridView` involucro 3 consultas incluyendo la que llena la `ComboBoxColumn`, me explico:

**Consulta ComboBoxColumn:**

```
//Asuma que este Dataset, YA contiene los datos...
//dataset_estatus

if (dataset_estatus.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dgrid_combobox_estatus.DataSource = dataset_estatus.Tables[0];
    dgrid_combobox_estatus.DisplayMember = "descripcion";
    dgrid_combobox_estatus.ValueMember = "codigo_estatus";
    dgrid_combobox_estatus.DataPropertyName = "codigo_estatus";
}
```

Los datos resultantes serían estos:

```
codigo_estatus | descipcion
       1            A
       2            B
       3            C
```

Esto carga los datos correctamente, lo que sucede es que el `DataGridView` lo lleno de datos combinados de dos consultas separadas por lo tanto antes de asignar el `DataSet` al `DataSource` que cargará los datos al `DataGridView` agrego 2 colunas en tiempo de ejecución al `Dataset` Entonces mientras voy combinando los datos de ambos `DataSet` con un valor de una de sus columnas debo **Seleccionar un Item especifico del `ComboBoxColumn`** Todo esto antes de asignar el `DataSource` del  `DataGridView`.

Aquí el código para representar este párrafo:

```
//Agregando 2 columnas que no pertenecen al Dataset
dataset_datos.Tables[0].Columns.Add("entrada", typeof(string));
dataset_datos.Tables[0].Columns.Add("salida", typeof(string));

for (int indice = 0; indice < dataset_datos.Rows.Count; indice++)
{
     //A las nuevas columnas le agrego los datos correspondiente del dataset de la otra consulta
     dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["entrada"] = otro_dataset.Rows[indice]["entrada"];
     dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["salida"] = otro_dataset.Rows[indice]["salida"];

     //Aqui debo asignar el SelectedValue del ComboBox 
     DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo = dataGridView1.Rows[indice].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
     combo.Value = Convert.ToInt32(otro_dataset.Rows[indice]["codigo_estatus"]);
}

//Luego de todo asigno el DataSource y se muestran los datos en el DataGridView
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset_datos.Tables[0];
```

> **El PROBLEMA** esta aqui: `DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo = dataGridView1.Rows[indice].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;` porque como el `DataGridView` aun no contiene datos dice: "Que el Indice esta fuera de rango" y es obvio. Lo que necesito es **seleccionar el `value` del ComboBoxColumn** con el valor proporcionado por: `otro_dataset.Rows[indice]["codigo_estatus"]`

**El Resultado final debería ser:**

```
Estatus | Entrada     | Salida      | Nombre | ...
   A      08:00 a.m.    12:00 p.m.    nombre1
   C      08:00 a.m.    12:00 p.m.    nombre2
   C      08:00 a.m.    12:00 p.m.    nombre3
```

> Los datos arrojados por `otro_dataset.Rows[indice]["codigo_estatus"]` en este caso fueron : `1`, `3`, `3` esos tienen que salir seleccionados al cargar los datos.

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010 y .NET NetFramework 4

Answer (score 1):

Intenta asignar los valores en los combobox después de asignar el datasource al datagridview. Con un for seria así:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset_datos.Tables[0];


for (int indice = 0; indice < otro_dataset_datos.Rows.Count; indice++)
{
     DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo = dataGridView1.Rows[indice].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
     combo.Value = Convert.ToInt32(otro_dataset.Rows[indice]["codigo_estatus"]);
}
```

Comment: De esta forma funciona, pero tengo que ver como hago para no tener que hacerlo de esta manera, ya que como se puede observar tengo que recorrer los datos dos veces, el primer `for` donde asigno los valores a las demas `columnas` y entonces volver a recorrer los datos para asignar el `valor` correspondiente a cada `combobox` , si no obtengo otra solución lo dejaré de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

prueba cuando los datos estén cargados

```
    dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
    }

    private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo = dataGridView1.Rows[indice].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        combo.Value = Convert.ToInt32(otro_dataset.Rows[indice]["codigo_estatus"]);
    }
```

Comment: Puede que funcione pero salta esta excepción: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll` y veo **dos inconvenientes** más con este método: **1** - Si llegara a funcionar *solo funcionaria cuando el `value` sea tipo `int` ?* , *Que pasaría si el `value` del `combobox` es tipo string?* ej: `F001`. **2** - Tengo que volver a recorrer todo el `datagridview` nuevamente para asignar los valores en `DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete` por lo tanto seria hacer el ciclo 2 veces.

Comment: si la asignación del evento DataBindingComplete la estas haciendo dentro del for, te puede dar ese error, se ha de realizar solo una vez

Comment: No lo hago dentro del for, esta fuera del `for`, incluso probé esto `dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;` luego que carga todo, dentro de un boton para hacer click e invocarlo, y sigue saltando el mismo error.

Comment: Si es posible pasame el código completo, no lo acabo de entender, lo siento:(

Comment: Debido a que es un proyecto de mi trabajo no puedo pasar el código. Intenté de esta forma: `var combo = dataset_datos.Tables[0].Rows[indice][0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;` creando la celda a partir del `dataset` no del `datagridview` pero al momento de asignar el valor `combo.Value = Convert.ToInt32(otro_dataset.Rows[indice]["codigo_estatus"]);` , da error : `object reference not set an instance of an object`  **¿Existe alguna forma de rellenar la celda en base a un dataset y no en base al datagridview?**